# Saving a boolean to a variable in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on an Access DB where I need to save a boolean to a variable.  Specifically, I pull the boolean results from a table using DLookUp and save them to a variable.  I then validate the boolean variable to whether it is true or not.  If it is true, then a check box appears on a form field I have in a separate document.  To test it, I made sure some of the values on the table were checked as true.  However, when I look to see what the variable is actually saving, it's either empty or false.  Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Correction: They are all showing as False.

Comment: Is your table bound to the form?  Then you wouldn't need to use a dlookup and just bind your variable to the checkbox.

Comment: And in case you can't use a bound control, you'll have to show us your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  They are not bound to the table.  Here's my logic and I've included the code below.  First i create a boolean variable.  Then I store the value in the variable and finally check to see if it's true.  For some reason it's just storing the default value of false instead of the actual value on the table. I'll include the code on the next post.

Comment: Dim blnCred As Boolean                                                                    blnCred = DLookup("CertF", "tblSpotChecks", "RecordID = " & Forms!frmSpotChecks.tbxCaseNumber)                                                                    If blnCred = True Then
        .FormFields("ckCred").CheckBox.Value = True
        Else
        .FormFields("ckCred").CheckBox.Value = False
    End If

Comment: not sure what the ".formfields" is doing.  why not just refer to your checkbox which I assume is called "ckcred".  Then your formula is just a reference to your forms control box.  `...THEN forms!FormName!CkCred = TRUE..."

Comment: Sorry. I should clarify.  The .FormFields is referring to a checkbox on a word document.  If there's a better way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

Comment: To help narrow down the failure point, how about confirming your DLookup is returning the proper value? Specifically, AFTER you set blnCred, display if true or false; use a record you know that should return a TRUE. If that's ok, then maybe you need to show more code that's wrapped around your dealing with the Word Doc.

Comment: Okay, since you're using ".formfields" I'm guessing that you have some sort of "WITH me" or "WITH forms!formname" type statement to go along with it.    Again, just make your control box = true (eg.  `THEN .FormFields = True`)

Comment: `dim blnCred as boolean` doesn't make sense to me as dlookups return string values. Shouldn't it be `dim blncred as string` and then `if blnCred= "true" then`?